# How can I print the log for a branch other than the current one?

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout, git-log, git-stash

I'm on a branch with some changes.  Changing branch is a pain as some files are locked by processes, so to change branch I'd have to stop all the processes which have locks, then `stash` the changes before checking out the other branch to see its log.

Is it possible to view the log for a different branch, without having to check it out?

Comment: Have your tried `git log <branch>`, where `<branch>` stands for the name of the branch of interest?

Comment: @Jubobs, no, I didn't.  I should just try the obvious before resorting to searching the internet and finding exotic suggestions around `cherry` and `rev-list`.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use

```
git log <branch>
```

where `<branch>` is the name of the branch of interest.

### From the `git-log` man-page...

A simplified version of the `git-log` synopsis given in [that command's man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) is

```
git log [<revision range>]
```

Further down, you can find the following passage:

> When no `<revision range>` is specified, it defaults to `HEAD` (i.e. the whole history leading to the current commit)

In others words, `git log` is equivalent to `git log HEAD`. If you're on a branch, called `mybranch`, say, this command is also equivalent to `git log mybranch`.

You want to limit the log to commits reachable from another branch, i.e. a branch you're not currently on. The easiest way to do that is to explicitly pass the name of the branch of interest to `git log`:

```
git log <branchname>
```

See the [gitrevisions manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more details about the many forms that the `<revision-range>` argument can take.

Comment: It seems like you must have the branch to be locally checked out first to run "git log" like this. At least git 2.27.0 behaves like this.

Comment: @a_girl Not sure what you mean by "locally checked out" here. You can run this on a local branch (e.g. `master`), whether it be checked out or not, and on a remote branch (e.g. `origin/master`).

Comment: ooooohhh, now I got it. I tried ```git log mybranch``` and it throw an error, but then, when I run ```git checkout mybranch; git checkout master; git log mybranch``` it worked even without "origin/". That's why I thought that I need to checkout my branch first. But I simply had to use "git log origin/mybranch" in order to look for a history of the remote branch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but maybe a helpful note to the answer:

Recently I got

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'other_branch_name': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

If logging for a single file is wanted than synopsis should be

```
git log other_branch_name -- relative_path_to_file
```

at least if the file relative_path_to_file does not exist in the other branch

I did not check if it applies for directories also but I expect the synopsis to be

```
git log other_branch_name -- relative_path_to_dir/
```